# Why does my java program throw java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when using JDA in heroku?

Tags: java, maven, heroku, discord-jda

I have this java discord bot hosted on Heroku, after upgrading to latest version of JDA i had to change `onGuildMessageReceived` to `onMessageReceived`.
When running my bot from intellij it works without any problem but when executing it from Heroku it gives me "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.AudioChannel net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.GuildVoiceState.getChannel()" every time I send a message on Discord.
The code that causes this error is: `AudioChannel audioChannel = e.getMember().getVoiceState().getChannel();` inside of `onMessageReceived`.

I personally feel that maven could be importing the wrong version to Heroku but I don't have any way to check it, so here it is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.furetto126.furettobot.FurettoBot</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.furetto126.furettobot</groupId>
    <artifactId>FurettoBot</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>dv8tion</id>
            <name>m2-dv8tion</name>
            <url>https://m2.dv8tion.net/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-alpha.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sedmelluq</groupId>
            <artifactId>lavaplayer</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.77</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` usually means there is jar conflicts, which suggets there is more than one jar file contains certain Class. You can simple double click `shift` in idea and search the certain class name to  check if there is more than on jar contains certain class

Comment: I tried this searching for "net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.GuildVoiceState.getChannel()" but there was just one result on the list

Comment: @Furetto126 I built a project using your pom file and really don't see multiple of the same Class. So in the next step, you can check whether there is a problem with the dependency version, and whether the corresponding class is loaded into the JVM.

Comment: Since in my project i couldn't see anything that could cause that i decided to delete the heroku app and remaking it, but that didn't solve any problem

Comment: just noticed that in my terminal when deploying to heroku it gives me this warning:  Discovered module-info.class. Shading will break its strong encapsulation